# Excel - how to open multiple CSV files each as a sheet

Tags: excel, automation, excel-2016

Is there a way to open multiple CSV files (from the same folder) and have them as individual sheets in the same workbook? Currently if I open multiple CSVs (multiple selection with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key pressed) each CSV is opened as a separate workbook - whereas what I need is a single workbook with each CSV as a worksheet in it.

***Update:-*** Obviously this can be done manually by adding each CSV as a sheet to a workbook - looking for a better automatic approach since this is a task I need to repeat over and over across many CSVs. e.g - I have a folder `csvs` with files `csv1.csv`, `csv2.csv`, `csv3.csv` etc. Need a workbook `Book1` with each CSV as a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro to load one or more CSV files into an already-open workbook (thanks to the "Record Macro" option and a little reverse engineering).

```
Sub LoadWorksheet()
'
' LoadWorksheet Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="path-to-file-you-want-to-load"
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Workbooks("currently-open-file").Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

The filename to replace `path-to-file-you-want-to-load` with is the first file you want to open as a worksheet. The `currently-open-file` is the blank Excel file that you want to load your other files into. Replace `Sheet1` with the name of the worksheet in the file that will be moved.

If there are multiple worksheets in the same file that you'll be moving over, repeat the `.Select` and `.Move` lines, and precede each pair with this line:

```
Windows("file-you-want-to-load").Activate
```

To open and copy over multiple files, just repeat the beginning part of the macro and populate it with the other file names.

*One thing to note:* This macro moves the sheets from one file to another, rather than copying them. So if there are multiple sheets in a file and you only move some of them, that workbook will remain open, and when you go to close it, Excel will prompt you to save it with the moved worksheet deleted. However, if you move all worksheets from that workbook, Excel will close that workbook without saving changes or prompting you to save changes.

Answer (score -1):

You could [import](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) the CSVs and add the data to a new sheet for each file.

Comment: that's obviously possible -  need a sort of automatic way of doing this.